# Mingw C++ not calling function

Tags: c++, assembly, mingw

So, i have the following function to read an EXTENDED (extended double, 80bit-precision double) and output as a normal INT

```
int read_ld( int addr )
{
    int result;
    asm volatile
    (
        "mov eax, %[addr];"
        "fld qword ptr [eax];"
        "fistp dword ptr %[result]"
        : [addr] "=m" (addr)
        : [result] "m" (result)
    );
 return result;
}
```

Wich is called by another function, (any function) but i will put here the actual code where i get the error

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void funca()
{
    if( key(VK_PRIOR) ) //Fast
            fps_control( 0 );
    else if( key(VK_NEXT) ) //Slow
        fps_control( fps * 2 );
    else
        fps_control( fps ); //Normal
    char a[255];
    if( key(VK_HOME) )
    {
        int k = read_ld( 0x5080EC ); //This is just for testing <<
    }
}
```

This EXACT code compiled with mingw, no special flags, gives me the following assembly at funca()

```
  SUB     ESP, 2C
  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP], 21
  CALL    nakaeru.6FF01540           << Notice these are calls to key(), normal
  TEST    EAX, EAX
  JE L017
  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP], 0
  CALL    nakaeru.6FF014E0           << Notice these are calls to key(), normal
L007:
  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP], 24
  CALL    nakaeru.6FF01540           << Notice these are calls to key(), normal
  TEST    EAX, EAX
  JE L014
  MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18] <<| This is my code and it is not a call
  FLD     QWORD PTR DS:[EAX]           |
  FISTP   DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+1C]        |
L014:
  ADD     ESP, 2C
  RETN
  LEA     ESI, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]
L017:
  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP], 22
  CALL    nakaeru.6FF01540           
  TEST    EAX, EAX
  MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[6FF08000]
  JE L026
  ADD     EAX, EAX
  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP], EAX
  CALL    nakaeru.6FF014E0          
  JMP L007
L026:
  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[ESP], EAX
  CALL    nakaeru.6FF014E0           
  JMP L007
```

I wanted to know why is the compiler doing this... Could it be some kind of optimization or some option i might be missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I won't put it as an answer because I'm a bit unsure, but it looks like your compiler has decided that your function `read_ld` was a good candidate for inlining. Thus, it directly put its body in your code instead of calling it.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly the case, but i have no clue why is it doing this way nor if there is any specific flag wich i could use to force it not to.

Comment: I don't know the details for MinGW, but MSVC for example has a flag that deactivate inline function expanding. There should be a similar thing for MinGW. Note that the `inline` keyword won't help, as your example shows, and is a perfect illustration that compiler don't need it (it's a hint for the compiler, nothing more).

Comment: From the GCC manual: you can specify the `-fno-inline` which specifies that functions shouldn't be inlined. Still, it's the default behavior when invoking GCC without optimization turned on. I'll check again the options you're using then (esp. if you're using an IDE and not the command line). Also: `Single functions can be exempted from inlining by marking them with the noinline attribute. `

Comment: To tell gcc (mingw) not inline just use something like this: "void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo() "

Comment: Actually, explicitly using -fno-inline worked! Also checked IDE for any flags and no optimization was being used, also didnt find any dumping the args to the compiler, looks like default behavior... Anyway, you have my thanks! If you could post it as an answer i could accept accept it